# を vs で - Which is more natural

Tags: particle-を, particle-で

What is the difference between the two following sentences?

> Fred san wa Nihongo o hanaseru

> Fred san wa Nihongo de hanaseru

Right now, I think the first using wo, is probably saying Fred can speak Japanese while the second one is saying he can speak using Japanese. Is this correct? Which is most natural?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a native speaker, but I think both are grammatical and natural depending on the context.

---

> **(A)** フレッドさんは日本語**を**話せる
>
> > Fred can speak Japanese

Because the object of 話せる is a language, it means 'to be able to speak that language.'

> **(B)** フレッドさんは日本語**で**話せる
>
> > Fred can speak **in** Japanese

By using で, it means 'to be able to speak using that language.' で marks the means, that is, the way something is done.

Note that 言う can be used as well, but the meaning is different.

> フレッドさんは日本語**で**言える
>
> > Fred can say it **in** Japanese.

**A** may be uttered as a response to 'Can Fred speak Japanese?' On the other hand, **B** may be uttered as a response to 'Can Fred speak in Japanese? I'm having a hard time understanding what he's saying **in** English.'

Another example with で:

> まだ英語でうまく話せません
>
> > I'm not good at speaking English yet.
>
> <sup>[Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A7%E8%A9%B1%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B%20%23sentences)</sup>

A literal translation for the above would be 'I can't *skillfully* speak English yet.'